# Converting SQL to Linq ("WHERE EXISTS")

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Can anyone help me to convert this SQL into LINQ?

```
SELECT * FROM Room_Type b
WHERE Exists(
 SELECT *
 FROM Room a 
 WHERE a.RoomId NOT IN
  (SELECT r.RoomId 
   FROM Reservation r
   WHERE NOT (r.DepartureDate<='2015-02-16' OR r.ArrivalDate > '2015-02-20' )
  )
)
```

Comment: I have tried this is sql server. It works fine. I just have no idea to convert it

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query using joins:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Room_Type rt 
    JOIN room r 
         ON r.RoomTypeId = rt.Id
    JOIN Reseration res
        ON res.RoomId = r.Id
WHERE NOT (r.DepartureDate<='2015-02-16' OR r.ArrivalDate > '2015-02-20' )))
```

Then you can use linq as follows:

```
DateTime departure = new DateTime(2015,02,16);
DateTime arrival = new DateTime(2015,02,20);
context.Reservation.Where(r.DepartureDate<= departure || r.ArrivalDate > arrival ).Select(res => res.Room.Room_Type)
```

Comment: Thanx xxMUROxx.. But I only get a single result. With above SQL I have different result.